# Merging Similar Observations in R

Tags: r, data-manipulation

I'm trying to use R to do some data management.

I have a data frame that as multiple variables (+200 columns) and many observation (+10,000 rows). There is a lot of missing data, and duplicated or uncompleted observations. 
One observation should be equal to one person (1 row = 1 unique person)

Here is dataset example (thank's to @aosmith)  :

```
dat = data.frame(email = c(rep(c("user1@hotmail.com", "user2@gmail.com"), each = 2), NA),
              name = c(NA, "Alfred C.", NA, "Bob V.", "Cathy L."),
              var1 = c(2, 2, NA, NA, 1),
              var2 = c(1, NA, 3, NA, 1),
              var3 = c(NA, NA, 1, 0, 2),
              var4 = c(0, NA, NA, NA, NA))
```

I want to merge my observations so that in the end, one row equals one person. To identify a person I use the email. When there is no email, I want to keep all observations (so if the email is missing, I dont want R to delete the observation. Every observation that as no email is considered as a unique observation).

For the times we can spot the same email address, we need R to update the fields of each variable when there is missing data with the data we get on the subsequent observations (with the same email address) we found . If there is already an existing data for one or more variable, We want R to create, each time a new variable to store the different values.

Here is an example to make this easier to understand.

We need to transform something like this :

```
          email        name    var1 var2 var3 var4 ... var200
user1@hotmail.com      <NA>     2    1   NA    0   ...   .
user1@hotmail.com    Alfred C.  2   NA   NA   NA   ...   .
  user2@gmail.com      <NA>    NA    3    1   NA   ...   .
  user2@gmail.com     Bob V.   NA   NA    0   NA   ...   .
             <NA>    Cathy L.   1    1    2   NA   ...   .
```

Into this something like this (combining rows with the same email and keep all the information for the same persons in one row but also by keeping the information when we cannot identify that the person is the same with the email address. So if email is NA we have to keep it as if it was a unique person) :

```
           email           name      var1    var2    var3a   var3b   var4   ...  var200

  user1@hotmail.com      Alfred C.     2       1      NA       NA     0      .      . 
    user2@gmail.com       Bob V.      NA       3      1        0      NA     .      . 
               <NA>      Cathy L.      1       1      2        .      NA     .      . 
    userX@email.com         .          .      etc    etc      etc    etc    etc    etc
```

Is there an easy way to do this ? I'm struggling with dplyr and tidyr two days...
In the end, one row should contain the information one person we were able to identify using the email variable. We need also keep all other observations that we could not identify as belonging to one person.

Thank you for your help and time!

Comment: Do you mean you either have an email, a twitter, or both?  Are the missing email values shown with NA?

Comment: twitter is just another variable, I think it's confusing so I will delete it from the example. We want to merge the observations coming from the same persons using their email address.

Comment: I updated my answer, which may or may not help.  It'd help if you'd put in a reproducible example dataset (your example dataset doesn't have any missing email values).

Comment: @aosmith I updated my question and added as you suggested a reproductible dataset

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I came up with an option in case you don't know how many values each variable within a subject will have.  You'll see most of the steps are for that (making separate names for separate columns).

The process is to put the dataset into long format using `gather`, removing missing and duplicate values for each subject and variable combination, making variable names for when there is more than one value per variable (add b, c, etc. to ends of variable names), and then putting the dataset back into wide format with `spread`.

```
dat = data.frame(email = rep(c("user1@hotmail.com", "user2@gmail.com"), each = 2),
                  twitter = c(NA, "user1", NA, "user2"),
                  var1 = c(2, 2, NA, NA),
                  var2 = c(1, NA, 3, NA),
                  var3 = c(NA, NA, 1, 0),
                  var4 = c(0, NA, NA, NA))
library(dplyr)
library(tidyr)

dat %>%
    gather(allvar, value, twitter:var4) %>%
    group_by(email, allvar) %>%
    filter(!is.na(value) & !duplicated(value)) %>%
    mutate(allvar2 = paste0(allvar, c("", letters[2:26])[1:n()])) %>% 
    ungroup() %>%
    select(-allvar) %>%
    spread(allvar2, value, convert = TRUE)

Source: local data frame [2 x 7]

              email twitter var1 var2 var3 var3b var4
1 user1@hotmail.com   user1    2    1   NA    NA    0
2   user2@gmail.com   user2   NA    3    1     0   NA
```

**Edit** for new example when some email addresses are missing

I'm not entirely clear if you always have either twitter or email information or both - if so, I think this could likely be simplified by filling in the twitter with `na.locf` like in @jazurro's answer and working with the combination of email and twitter as the the grouping variable.

To keep rows with no email, you could filter them out, do everything you need, and then `rbind_list` them back in.  In this case naming duplicated variables, e.g., `var3` and `var3b` will work out for you (it is possible to name them `var3a`, `var3b` instead, but won't work for this rbinding method).

```
dat = data.frame(email = c(rep(c("user1@hotmail.com", "user2@gmail.com"), each = 2), NA),
                  twitter = c(NA, "user1", NA, "user2", "user3"),
                  var1 = c(2, 2, NA, NA, 1),
                  var2 = c(1, NA, 3, NA, 1),
                  var3 = c(NA, NA, 1, 0, 2),
                  var4 = c(0, NA, NA, NA, NA))

dat %>%
    filter(!is.na(email)) %>% # filter out rows with missing email
    gather(allvar, value, twitter:var4, na.rm=TRUE) %>%
    group_by(email, allvar) %>%
    distinct(value) %>%
    mutate(allvar2 = paste0(allvar, c("", "b")[1:n()])) %>% # Name duplicated variables, ex: var3, var3b
    # OP gets error using n(); use length(value) instead
    ungroup() %>%
    select(-allvar) %>%
    spread(allvar2, value, convert = TRUE) %>% # Make sure spread converts variables appropriately
    rbind_list(.,dat[is.na(dat$email),]) # rbind rows with missing email

Source: local data frame [3 x 7]

              email twitter var1 var2 var3 var3b var4
1 user1@hotmail.com   user1    2    1   NA    NA    0
2   user2@gmail.com   user2   NA    3    1     0   NA
3                NA   user3    1    1    2    NA   NA
```

Comment: +1 for a `tidyr` solution. I haven't tried it yet myself, but I like the look of this.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. I made my example more clear. I tested with my data, but it leaves me with on variable "email" and all X as observations... I trying to find out why.

Comment: I see the twitter might be confusing... it's just a variable. I edited it in the example. I'm trying to run the code

Comment: I'm getting this : "Error: index out of bounds
In addition: There were 50 or more warnings (use warnings() to see the first 50)" ? Do you have any idea what might cause this ?

Comment: @aosmith When I use your dataset I get this "Error in n() : This function should not be called directly
In addition: Warning message:
attributes are not identical across measure variables; they will be dropped"

Comment: @leakciM That error message can happen if you've loaded **plyr** *after* **dplyr**.  I believe the warning has to do with putting categorical and numerical variables into a single column (I also get it, which prompted me to turn the continuous variables back to numeric at the end of my edit).

Comment: @aosmith I'm stuck... Even if I restart R load plyr first or dont load it at all, I'm still getting the same Error in n() : This function should not be called directly...

Comment: Thank you @aosmith, it works for the data set with now with "length(value)". The problem in the real data set is that the variables are not all numerical. How do you deal with it when there are different types of variables ? Should I update another time the example ?

Comment: @leakciM Edited to add the `convert` argument in `spread`, which should take care of this.

Comment: +1 @aosmith just checked this morning, everything seems to work fine on a small sample!! thank you for your help! Now just have to see how many hours will have my computer to run the code for the millions of observations ;)